# SLURM doesn't recognize the commands in prolog script

Tags: slurm

I run commands such as:
ifconfig, sminfo in SLURM prolog script, but these commands are not executed and return error: command not found and empty output if I check the output text file. If I try commands such as: ls, hostname; they are working well.
I tried to execute the script manually it's working and the commands: sminfo, ifconfig working well.

What is the problem ??

## my script:

```
 #!/bin/bash

echo "==Pre job==:"
work_dir=`scontrol strong textshow job $SLURM_JOBID | grep ' WorkDir' | awk '{print $1}' | awk -F'=' '{print $2}'`
sminfo_out=`sminfo`
cd $work_dir
echo $sminfo_out > /tmp/sminfo_out3
python check_sm.py --sm_input "$sminfo_out"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second sentence of the [Slurm documentation on prolog and epilog scripts](https://slurm.schedmd.com/prolog_epilog.html) reads:

> Note that for security reasons, these programs do not have a search
>   path set. Either specify fully qualified path names in the program or
>   set the "PATH" environment variable

So you either set `PATH` explicitly at the beginning of your script (run `echo $PATH` to find out what it contains) or you use the full path to the commands you are running (use `which command`  to find out the full path to a command).